# How to render HTML file received as response from nodejs into react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a function in backend(nodejs, express) which returns html file as response using `sendFile`.

I want to render this html file response in frontend(React) of the application.

I tried using `document.write` in frontend to display html file but that redirects localhost from http to https.

Is there any way to render this html file in frontend?

Comment: I guess, you're looking for [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). However, I'd recommend to avoid that by all means for both security and performance considerations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property allows you to set the HTML-markup into an element in React.

Just try:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}} />
```

`data` is a the HTML-markup.